# Django migratons are failing when adding a new field

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to add a new field to my postgreSql database in another server. When adding a new field named 'aceptada' at ReservaSimple in [models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igsh0.png)

After applying the change I used

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations

python3 manage.py migrate
```

However, it says no changes were detected and that I shouldn't re upload the model. [Migration error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kHUN.png)

I've tried to drop the database and migrate again with the new model.py file changed with the new attribute, but when I do the migration, no changes are applied to the columns of postgreSql.I've also tried deleting the migrations directory in the app and migrating again and creating the column manually. However, when running the server I always get this error. [server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t24Q.png)

Edit:

I've tried to follow the next steps:

Drop the database

```
kafka_db=# DROP DATABASE final_db;
DROP DATABASE
```

Remove the added field from models.py

```
class ReservaSimple(models.Model):
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField(null = False)
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(null = False)
    comentarios = models.CharField(null = False, blank = True, max_length = 50)
    costo_final = models.FloatField(null = True)
```

Remove the added field from serializers.py

```
class ReservaSimpleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
            model = ReservaSimple
            fields = ('fecha_inicio', 'fecha_fin', 'comentarios', 'costo_final')
```

Create database

```
kafka_db=# CREATE DATABASE final_db OWNER ROOT;
CREATE DATABASE
```

Run migrate

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Response

```
Running migrations:
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
Applying aplicacion.0001_initial... OK
Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Added the field again to models.py

```
class ReservaSimple(models.Model):
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField(null = False)
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(null = False)
    comentarios = models.CharField(null = False, blank = True, max_length = 50)
    costo_final = models.FloatField(null = True)
    aceptada = models.IntegerField(null = True)
```

Added the field to serializers.py

```
class ReservaSimpleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
            model = ReservaSimple
            fields = ('fecha_inicio', 'fecha_fin', 'comentarios', 'costo_final', 'aceptada')
```

Made migrations

```
m.leona@ISIS2503-015:~/nidooFinal$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py:299: 
RuntimeWarning: Model 'aplicacion.reservasimple' was already registered. 
Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most 
notably 
with related models.
new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
No changes detected
```

Run migrate

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, aplicacion, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
```

Made select * from table

```
final_db=# select * from aplicacion_reservasimple;
id | fecha_inicio | fecha_fin | comentarios | costo_final 
----+--------------+-----------+-------------+-------------
(0 rows)

final_db=#
```

Comment: Please in future paste your code and traceback here as code, rather than linking to images. Anyway, I don't understand 'add a new field to my postgreSql database in another server'. What other server? It this an existing production environment with data or currently just local?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm running my postgreSql in another host (the ip that appears in the last image... 172.24.41.148:8083) and i'm trying to add a new column to the table when migrating, but I can't add it.

Comment: Not sure but it seems you miss a step here. The first error is probably due to some inconsistency between your database and the migration files. So if you can drop your database you should. But then make sure you follow the correct steps in this order: 1. drop your database 2. remove the extra field in your model (go back to a state of your code consistent with your migration files) 3. run `migrate` 4. add the field again 5. run `makemigrations` 6. run `migrate`.

Comment: Or if you don't have any other database that needs migrating: drop the database, delete all your migration files and run `makemigrations` to create new, clean migrations. Then run `migrate`.

Comment: Edited the post with new information.

Comment: can you try loading your virtualenv and running `makemigrations` in a plain shell (not ipython)? I think the error you see comes from a circular import, check where else you're importing `ReservaSimple`, maybe in an `__init__` file somewhere or in another model file.

Comment: Or did you change something in `admin.py` and register your model twice (once via the default `admin.site.register()` and later added custom admin using `@admin.register` decorator?

Comment: All of the __init__.py files have no code in them. While, admin.py is 
 `from django.contrib import admin
from . models import Parking
from . models import Espacio
from . models import PNDemandante
from . models import ReservaSimple
from . models import Vehiculo

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Parking)
admin.site.register(Espacio)
admin.site.register(PNDemandante)
admin.site.register(ReservaSimple)
admin.site.register(Vehiculo) `